# Vectorizer where or how fit information is stored?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

in text mining/classification when a vectorizer is used to transform a text into numerical features, in the training `TfidfVectorizer(...).fit_transform(text)` or `TfidfVectorizer(...).fit(text)` is used. In testing it supposes to utilize former training info and just transform the data following the training fit.

In general case the test run(s) is completely separate from train run. But it needs some info regarding the fit obtained during the training stage otherwise the transformation fails with error `sklearn.utils.validation.NotFittedError: idf vector is not fitted` . It's not just a dictionary, it's something else.

What should be saved after the training is done, to make the test stage passing smoothly?

In other words train and test are separated in time and space, how to make test working, utilizing training results?

Deeper question would be what 'fit' means in scikit-learn context, but it's probably out of scope

Answer (score 0):

In the test phase you should use the same model names as you used in the trainings phase. In this way you will be able to use the model parameters which are derived in the training phase. Here is an example below;

- First give a name to your vectorizer and to your predictive algoritym (It is NB in this case)

> vectorizer = TfidVectorizer()
>
> classifier = MultinomialNB()

- Then, use these names to vectorize and predict your data

> trainingdata_counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(trainingdata.values)
>
> classifier.fit(trainingdata_counts, trainingdatalabels)
>
> testdata_counts = vectorizer.transform(testdata.values)
>
> predictions=classifier.predict(testdata_counts)

By this way, your code will be able to process training and the test phases continuously.

Comment: I'm sorry but you completely missed the question